# Nextjs Data URLs for blurDataURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, next.js, uri

With NextJS 11, we can use `Image` component with a blur placeholder.
If we want to use it with dynamic image we have to use [blurDataURL](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#blurdataurl) which is a Data URL.

I would like to get my original image and make it smaller like 10x10 px. When I try to use an already created other image that is in my public folder with `fs.readFileSync('http://localhost:3000/1blur.png','base64')` but I got this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://localhost:3000/1blur.png'` and when I try to open the file it's working in my navigator.

So, I have 2 questions :

- Why do I have an error ?
- How can I dynamically transform my original image into 10x10 blured img that I can use with Data URL ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use [`plaiceholder`](https://plaiceholder.co/docs/usage) for this. Ref.: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18858 ;; For first question, you can do try doing: `fs.readFileSync('../public/1blur.png', {encoding: 'base64'})` -- modify the path as suitable. `../` means 1 directory up, `../../` means 2 ...

Answer (score 7):

you can write your own custom fun and use you placeholder image as an svg src for that.
i achived by doing this

```
export default function TestComponents({bannerImage}) {
  const styles = ['bg-primary', 'bg-blue'];
  const newImageSrc = bannerImage.toString().replace(/[()]/g, '');
    const convertImage = (w, h) => `
  <svg width="${w}" height="${h}" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="g">
        <stop stop-color="#333" offset="20%" />
        <stop stop-color="#222" offset="50%" />
        <stop stop-color="#333" offset="70%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="${w}" height="${h}" fill="#333" />
    <rect id="r" width="${w}" height="${h}" fill="url(#g)" />
    <animate xlink:href="#r" attributeName="x" from="-${w}" to="${w}" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"  />
  </svg>`;

  const toBase64 = (str) =>
    typeof window === 'undefined'
      ? Buffer.from(str).toString('base64')
      : window.btoa(str);

  return (
    <div
      
      className="bg-white rounded-lg md:space-x-6 space-y-6 text-center shadow-lg  group my-4  hover:-translate-y-3 eas-in-out duration-500 cursor-pointer"
    >
      <div className="relative">
        <Image
          src={newImageSrc}
          alt="Picture of the author"
          layout="responsive"
          placeholder="blur"
          width={700}
          height={475}
          className="rounded-t"
          blurDataURL={`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${toBase64(
            convertImage(700, 475)
          )}`}
        />
</div>
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per NextJS [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#blurdataurl), you can use the **Shimmer** effect as blurDataURL which will basically generate an svg with linear gradient color and a nice animate pulse on top of it.

here is an example:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/image-component/pages/shimmer.tsx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34756403)